# How can I return git master branch back?

Tags: git, gitlab

This is my master branch on gitlab. I want to undo the previous commit as master is not working now.

Using terminal, I should switch to master branch and then:

```
git revert f23...
```

[image]

This is the pipeline for more information and I want to go back to the arrow:

[image]

Comment: Well, if you ware going to mask some information from a picture, what's the point if you can read them anyway? You want to `git revert @^^^`?

Comment: [Does this help?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/927358/how-do-i-undo-the-most-recent-local-commits-in-git/927386#927386)

Comment: `revert` and `reset` are very different things.

Comment: @KamilCuk I am not sure what is the best approach. do you recommend something else other than revert?

Comment: I do not believe a "recommendation" is possible - that solely depends on what _you_ want to do - if you want to _revert_ the commit or _reset_ current head to that commit. That's different.

Answer (score 2):

you can try with

```sh
git reset --soft "HEAD~3"
```

this will remove your first 3 commits.
Next you can run:

```sh
# remove the staged files
git restore --staged .

# remove the changed files
git checkout -- .
```

Now do some change and run:

```sh
# add your change
git add .

# commit the change
git commit -m "my change"

# force the push and replace the history
git push -f
```